# Need help with Equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X$ is an infinite set and $x$ is in $X$, show that $X \sim X \setminus \{x\}$.

Should I start by using proof by contradiction? Like, assume that $X \not\sim X \setminus \{x\}$ and get a contradiction?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sim$ in this context? Is it a general equivalence relation?

Comment: Yes, the one with all the symmetric, reflexive, transitive properties, etc etc

Comment: I understand $\sim$ here to mean that there is a bijection between the two sets.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:  First show that it is true if $X$ is countable, by explicitly constructing the mapping.  Then let $X$ be possibly uncountable.  It still contains a countable subset $Y$, so…

(I would not try to use contradiction. I would explicitly construct the equivalence mapping.)

Comment: By "constructing the mapping", should the function from X to Y be bijective? From my lecture, that is the requirement to satisfy the definition of X ~ Y.

Comment: Yes. The most straightforward way to show that $P\sim Q$ is to construct a bijective mapping from $P$ to $Q$. Here I am suggesting that you first construct a bijective mapping $f:X\leftrightarrow X\setminus\{x\}$ when $X$ is countable, then consider the case where $X$ is uncountable but has a countable subset $Y$ and construct the mapping $f:X\leftrightarrow X\setminus\{x\}$ for that case.

Comment: When $Y$ is a countably infinite set, the way to show that $Y\setminus\{y\}$ has the same cardinality as $Y$ can be seen by viewing $Y$ as $\{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,\ldots\}$ and $Y\setminus\{y\}$ as $\{y_2,y_3,y_4,\ldots\}$, and think about how to create a bijection between those two sets.  If $Y$ is a countably infinite subset of $X$ and $x\not\in Y$, I'd let $Y=\{y_2,y_3,y_4,\ldots\}$ and let $y_1=x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Can I say f(n)=y_(n+1) so that for every y_n in Y, I would get y_(n+1) in Y \ {y}. I don't know if that makes sense though.

Comment: If you say $f(y_n)=y_{n+1}$, that will do it.